# Updating to the head of a named branch in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

How do I update to the head of a named branch (regardless if it is tip or not)?  When I pull form the server (hg pull --branch [named branch]) the repo does not go to the head of that branch.  I would try updating to tip but the head of the named branch is not necessarily the tip.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it with:

```
hg update branchname
```

which updates you to the "most tipward head on that branch" becuase, of course, a branch can have multiple heads.

When you do `hg pull --branch branchname` what you're doing is pulling "all the changesets on branch branchname and all the changesets not on branchname that are ancestors of any changeset on branchname" which isn't terribly useful.

You're better off just doing the update after the pull.